# how to create syntax for url rewriting

Tags: url, rewriting

i have got this url like below :

```
    http://www.mylink.com/property?id=34455
```

whats the rule to rewrite it to be in the following form without breaking 
the css or anything. I see it done on multiple websites

```
    http://www.mylink.com/property/3455
```

i already tried

```
           RewriteRule ^property/?$ property.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: apache web server running PHP

Answer (score 1):

If the URL to be rewrited to `http://www.mylink.com/property/3455` is `http://www.mylink.com/property.php?id=34455` (notice the "**.php**" after property), the rule could be this one:

```
RewriteRule ^property/([0-9]+)$ property.php?id=$1
```

You can test your rules here http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/